# Op-amp connected as a differential amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am testing an op-amp connected as a differential amplifier.
I am using two function generators for the two input signals.
I am using an oscilloscope to view the input signals and the output signal at three different channels.

The problem is that one of the input signals when displayed at the oscilloscope is continuously moving (it's not stable on the screen) and the result is not the correct subtraction of the two input signals. The output signal is also moving, and it keeps increasing and decreasing. How to solve this problem?

Comment: `a differential amplifier`? Do you mean 'a difference amplifier (subtractor)'? To clarify, please add your circuit drawing

Comment: FYI unfortunately the built-in Stack Exchange (private Imgur-based) image upload is currently broken - see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382854/image-uploading-fails-with-failed-to-upload-image-an-error-occurred-on-the-ser) (and so is the public Imgur). So temporarily, another image upload site will have to be used :(

Comment: You might try this test: Apply ONE function generator to both inputs. If your amplifier is a proper difference amplifier, output should be a straight line with no hint of any input signal frequency.

Comment: If your functions generators are master clocked-based (as DDS generators), then you should synchronize one input master clock with the other output master clock. And you should work with the same output frequency or an "harmonic".

Answer (score 4):

> *The problem is that one of the input signals when displayed at the
> oscilloscope is continuously moving*

Unless you somehow lock the two input signals in frequency to some integer value, the oscilloscope screen will appear to be unstable. This is because you can only trigger the oscilloscope on one channel and if channel 2 (for instance) isn't locked in frequency to channel 1 then it will appear to rapidly drift across the screen.

One solution is to use use single-shot mode if your oscilloscope has that facility.

> *the result is not the correct subtraction of the two input signals.*

If your difference amplifier is correctly wired then it's highly likely that the result is the correct solution and that your confusion arises because of the screen appearing to move and increase/decrease; this is normal.

Another solution is to use one signal generator that has multiple shape outputs (such as square/triangle and sine). They will be frequency locked but can be easily seen to be additive/subtractive if they feed the two inputs of the difference amplifier.

Alternatively, use a square wave output for one signal input and simultaneously filter that output and feed it to the other input. The filtered signal will appear to be more triangular in nature but, importantly, you will have two different shaped signals that are frequency locked and hence your oscilloscope screen will appear stable.

Comment: It sounds like the scope is not triggering. Trigger on the input signal and look for the trigger light to illuminate on the scope. Once it is locked the display should be stable.

Answer (score 0):

The trace on an oscilloscope move from left to right starting at the trigger point in time. It sweeps across the screen then starts over when it reaches the right side. To trigger, a voltage level is set. When the level is crossed the sweep starts.

Periodic signals always trigger at the same phase. Aperiodic signal will not trigger.

Only one channel can trigger a sweep. The other channel “appears” stable only if phase locked. Signals from different generators cannot be phase locked even if there frequencies are set to the same value. So the other channel will appear to move one direction or the other.

**So the oscilloscope is displaying the truth.**

Your description of the subtractor output increasing and decreasing is exactly what is expected by subtracting two signals of almost the same frequency. This is the case where two generators un-synchronized generators set to the same frequency are applied to the subtractor input.

As the phase between the two signals drifts between in- phase and anti- phase, the output will increase and decrease.

**So both the circuit and oscilloscope as well as your observations are correct.**